# What makes DosBox on web.archive.org so slow despite JIT?

Tags: performance, browser, jit, emscripten, dosbox

I wanted to see if I could play [Exile 2 from web.archive.org](https://archive.org/details/win3_ExileII-) and I found that I need to install it first, which takes ages. Given that I'm basically emulating x86 machine on an x86 computer, DosBox supports dynarec (dynamic recompilation) and contemporary browsers support JITing the JavaScript code (and Emscripten generates asm.js, which should be rather easy to JIT), what makes it all so slow? In other words, what could be the bottleneck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dosbox is compiled using [Emterpreter](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Emterpreter), which makes it slower than the pure asmjs version:

The **Emterpreter** is an option that compiles asm.js output from Emscripten into a binary bytecode. It also generates an interpreter ("Emscripten interpreter", hence Emterpreter) capable of executing that bytecode. This lets you compile your project, or parts of your project, into bytecode that will be interpreted, as opposed to asm.js that will be executed directly by the JavaScript engine.

The second reason is, that the `Dynamic recompilation` in the emscripten port of dosbox is not available yet. It would be a lot of work, to make it possible to create asmjs code on the fly.